# RequireJS and AngularJS: Calling a controller from another using RequireJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I am loading my AngularJS app via RequireJS. My `index.html` have a button and on `ng-click` it opens a BootstrapUI-Modal i.e On `ng-click`, the function `open()` is called in my `first` controller. Now in the open() function, it calls `second` controller and template.html.
This works fine as an Angular module. But when I do it via RequireJS, the open() function is not able to call `second` controller. Any help please

In simple words, how to call a controller from another controller using RequireJS

```
function first($scope, $uibModal, $log, $rootScope) { //First controller
  console.log("c1");
  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;
  $scope.open = function (divid, $event) {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'angreq/app/templates/template.html',
      controller: 'second',
      windowClass: 'large-Modal',
    });
  };
}


//second controller
function second($scope, $window, createEmojiIcon, $rootScope) {
  console.log("second");
}
```

Comment: how do you load the ```second``` controller? or how do you registering second controller into your app?

Comment: Thats the confusion for me. I dont know how to do it. This is my first requireJS app. I tried searching a lot but till now I got no luck on how to do that.  My `first` controller gets loaded via `$routeProvider`, but `second` controller needs to be called from `first`. Its confusing for me on how to do it

Comment: I see, then I will suggest you to use ```angularAMD```. It made for simplifying the troubles you will got when going angualar + requireJS. And you will solve your problem if you can integrate ```angularAMD``` into your app.

Comment: Right now it shows an Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'second' is not a function, got undefined. Will try using angularAMD, hope it will make my life easier

Comment: Yes, by your comment I known it will took you maybe a week to fully wrap your head around angular + requireJS. So go for angulaeAMD you will shorten it to 1-3 days depent on your knowledge about both libraries.